# How to install Homebrew on Jelastic

Tags: centos, homebrew, jelastic

I needed to install a repository with brew on my Jelastic Environment, and I ended up facing many difficulties to achieve this, so I decided to share my solution here, hope it helps others out.

Comment: But why? If your goal is to just install composer there are far easier ways. Is there another use case where you're using `brew`?

Comment: Not just for composer, that was an example, I needed to install a few repositories with over 30 dependencies each, so I really needed to make brew work.

Comment: Fair enough. I was just curious because most/all add-ons (JPS packages) tend to be written with the assumption they are installed into a clean/default state, so making a major deviation such as git and curl version upgrades has the potential for unintended breakages elsewhere (though your WARNING is helpful). I'd favour using a custom image via docker template for such heavy customisations.

Comment: Sadly I'm not familiar with docker templates (or docker at all), I would have liked to create my own template to have an easier setup, but I ended up with this hahaha

Also git and curl are not really updated, jelastic still uses it's own version, I just installed new local versions and overwritten the path for cli usage, you can still use the base binaries if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a hell of a run, but here is the detailed procedure:

**WARNING: ONLY USE THE PACKAGE INSTALLER OF POINT 1 AS LAST RESOURCE, IT CAN CAUSE MANY PROBLEMS.
For example: using it to install composer will downgrade your php binary to v5 permanently, and there is nothing you can do to fix it unless creating a new node, if you decide to use it, first clone your node to have a backup in case it destroyes everything.**

1. Install this package installer following the instructions here: https://github.com/jelastic-jps/packages-installer :

`Then use it to install gcc.`

2. We need to install anaconda in order to update git and curl to a version recent enough to make brew at least run (src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52561058/12181662 ) :

`curl https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh > Miniconda.sh bash Miniconda.sh -b -p ~/conda`

3. Use anaconda to install git and curl (src: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/lzdo9n/comment/gq1fhak/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3 ) :

```
source /var/www/conda/bin/activate

conda update conda
conda install git
conda install curl

conda deactivate

echo 'export PATH="/var/www/conda/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
export PATH="/var/www/conda/bin:$PATH"
```

4. install brew locally (src: https://brew.sh/ ) :

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

echo 'eval "$(/var/www/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /var/www/.bash_profile
eval "$(/var/www/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

echo 'export HOMEBREW_CURL_PATH="/var/www/conda/bin/curl"' >> ~/.bash_profile
export HOMEBREW_CURL_PATH="/var/www/conda/bin/curl"
echo 'export HOMEBREW_GIT_PATH="/var/www/conda/bin/git"' >> ~/.bash_profile
export HOMEBREW_GIT_PATH="/var/www/conda/bin/git"
```

5. install the most recent version of gcc using brew (src: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/101919#issuecomment-1162740031 ) :

```
brew install gcc@5
brew install --force-bottle gcc
```

6. fix brew install for the non-root locations (src: https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/3421#discussioncomment-3126807 ) :

```
echo 'export HOMEBREW_RELOCATE_BUILD_PREFIX=1' >> /var/www/.bash_profile
export HOMEBREW_RELOCATE_BUILD_PREFIX=1
```

7. enjoy! Example: `brew install composer`

Also you can try to run this is you face any errors during installation of anything:

`brew link --overwrite libxcrypt`